# iPad: Sample project AVCapture: Rotate the video preview for different orientations?

Tags: ipad, orientation, video-capture

iPad: Sample project AVCapture: How do you rotate the video preview for different orientations?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to take the easy way, just don't support any orientation besides UIInterfaceOrientation and the image will be correctly displayed.

Otherwise, you'll have to apply a translation to the preview layer opposite that of the interface orientation in your `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` method. For example, UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft is (IIRC) a 90° clockwise rotation. So apply a 90° counterclockwise rotation to the preview layer to compensate.

Comment: How do you apply a rotation to a view layer?

Comment: Use the layer's [affineTransform](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CALayer/setAffineTransform:) or [transform](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CALayer/transform) properties. Or put it in a view and use the view's [transform](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/transform) prop.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use:

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    [CATransaction begin];
    self.prevLayer.orientation = toInterfaceOrientation; //AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer
    self.prevLayer.frame = self.view.frame;
    [CATransaction commit];

    [super willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];
}
```